# Convert from NHibernate to Entity Framework checking type of an instance

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, structuremap

The team I am working with has been given the task of converting an MVC 4 application from using FluentNHibernate to using Entity Framework 5.

The project is using StructureMap for the Dependency Injection.  Currently the IOC looks like this:

```
ForSingletonOf<ISessionFactory>().Use(SessionConfiguration.get_session_factory);

For<ISession>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
    .Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .EnrichWith((ISession session) => new TransactionManagementSessionDecorator(session));
```

The project contains some Object Extensions, one of those being the following:

```
public static bool is_instance_of<T>(this object instance)
{
    if (instance is INHibernateProxy)
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>().GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Unproxy(instance) is T;

    return instance is T;
}
```

The above extension would be used for example like this:

```
CartItemType get_cart_item_type(Registration registration)
{
    if (registration.is_instance_of<FirstTimeRegistration>())
        return CartItemType.FirstTime;

    if (registration.is_instance_of<ReplacementRegistration>())
        return CartItemType.Replacement;

    if (registration.is_instance_of<RenewalRegistration>())
        return CartItemType.Renewal;
               ...
               ...

    throw new ArgumentException("Registration Type is unknown");
}
```

The classes FirstTimeRegistration, ReplacementRegistration and RenewalRegistration all inherit the Registration class.

The following has been added to our IOC for the conversion to EF:

```
For<RegistrationContext>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
    .Use(x => new RegistrationContext());

For(typeof(IEFRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EFRepository<>));
```

The problem I seem to be having is figuring out how I can change the is_instance_of<> extension to work with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shooting from the hip here (I don't know that much about NHibernate), what about using Type.IsInstanceOfType() from the framework [(ref msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx)?

So your code would look like

```
CartItemType get_cart_item_type(Registration registration)
{
    if (typeof(FirstTimeRegistration).IsInstanceOfType(registration))
    return CartItemType.FirstTime;

    if (typeof(ReplacementRegistration).IsInstanceOfType(registration))
    return CartItemType.Replacement;

    if (typeof(RenewalRegistration).IsInstanceOfType(registration))
    return CartItemType.Renewal;
           ...
           ...

    throw new ArgumentException("Registration Type is unknown");
}
```

The expression looks slightly backwards, but...

Comment: This appears to work fine, even with proxied classes.  Thanks.

Comment: I did it this way so the code using the method was unchanged.
    `public static bool is_instance_of<T>(this object instance)
     {
         return typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(instance);
     }`

Comment: Even better. I tried it out in my project, and Resharper suggested an even simpler line: `return instance is T;`

Answer (score 1):

You might be in trouble here. NHibernate supports a lot of things Entity Framework 5 (or even 6) doesn't support. I was surprised as well, but after some [research](http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2013/03/entity-framework-56-vs-nhibernate-3.html), I'm quite sure you have a mission impossible.